# Python function to return property of function construct

Tags: python

Found this construct in the source of some python package (and it's probably more common). What is done with this?

```
def fie(x):
    def foo(y):
        return 123
    return property(foo)
```

When trying on a scratchpad I can't do anything with the outcome:

```
fie(3)
<property object at 0x04D1BDE0>

fie(3)(4)
'property' object is not callable
```

Comment: `fie(3).fget(4)` returns `123`, though I have no idea what the point of this would be.

Comment: Can you please give more context around where you found this code, or the exact code itself? Calling `property(foo)` is typically used to define a "managed attribute" inside of a class definition (https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property). So, you can do something like `instance.fie`, and it invokes `fie`. If we have more context around the code, we can maybe see why the author is doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function "fie" creates a data descriptor having only a getter, which returns always "123" on every instance "y" is used.

The parameter "y" needed by the protocol even if we bring back a constant, while "x" in the example is not used and confusing, so let we change it a bit:

```
def fie(x):
    def foo(y):
       print "Returning x"
       return x
return property(foo)

class Dog(object):
    age = fie(3)

>>> Dog.age
<property object at 0x1050565d0>

>>> pluto = Dog()
>>> pluto.age
Returning x
3
>>> pluto.age = 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#239>", line 1, in <module>
    pluto.age = 5
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

As you can see, with our new *fie* function we create an attribute named *age* with the constant value of *3* on the class *Dog*. When invoked on the class we still see it as the property's protocol wrapper, but on instance *pluto* it happens the magic. And because we defined only the getter, the property is read-only.

Note that the class must be of the new-style (i.e. inheriting from *object*), otherwise the assignment would work and overwrite forever the wrapper, changing the attribute *age* into an actual integer value within the instance's dictionary:

```
class Dog2:
     age = fie(7)

>>> ploto = Dog2()
>>> ploto.age
Returning original x
7
>>> ploto.age = 8
>>> ploto.age
8
```

Comment: That's it! The function is declared outside of a class to than be used to generate multiple similar but different methods in a class. This way one has to type the code for that method only once. If you also want the class method to behave like a property you have to use the property() function.